# iPhone Objective-C JSON Parser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

Has anyone had issues with a size limit on a returned JSON Object using the JSON Parser that is available for the iPhone?

I am using [this open-source JSON Framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/downloads/list) (I am using the latest version)

If I reduce the size of the returned JSON my app will run just fine. If the object gets too large, the app crashes with the below error:

```
-JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 UserInfo=0x4141580 "Unrecognised leading character"
```

Don't be fooled though... it has nothing to do a leading character except that it seems to split the JSON at a certain size and then ends up with a random leading character because the next JSON string starts with a random character.

Comment: Odd. I've used json-framework in the past and not had any trouble. How long is your json message exactly? It could be a bug, have you reported it to the json-framework developer?

Comment: Turns out I was wrong... see below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I was wrong. I was trying to parse the JSON in a didReceiveData callback method, which gets called multiple times as data is received. I needed to concatenate the result as it came in and then parse the JSON in connectionDidFinishLoading.

Thanks for looking.